# csv file reading only first line

Tags: c#, string, csv

I'm trying to upload a series of client info's through a csv ,I had some trouble with this in the eginning but my previous post was answered so I was able to start reading in the data however it only reads the first line. Just wondering if anyone had any ideas. I've included the code below

```
    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //Browse for file
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        //Only show .csv files
        ofd.Filter = "Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File|*.csv";
        DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();

        //If the user selects a valid file 
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //File is delimited by a comma
            char[] laClientDelim = { ',' };

            //New object for string manipulation
            objStringManipulation = new StringManipulation();

            // Parse the csv file
            List<string[]> lsClientList = objStringManipulation.parseCSV(ofd.FileName, laClientDelim);

            foreach (string[] laClient in lsClientList)
            {
                //Create new object for manipulating the database
                objSqlCommands = new SqlCommands("Client", "ClientName");



                string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName); // read the file completely line by line
                char splitChar = ',';
                int splitCharCount = 0;
                int k = 0;


                    string[] fields = records[k].Split(splitChar);  // reads all the single values per line. 'splitChar' should be the delimiter.
                    splitCharCount++;
                    if (splitCharCount >= 4 && splitCharCount <= 10)
                    {
                        var stuff = from l in File.ReadLines(ofd.FileName)
                                    let x = l.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                              .Skip(1)
                                             .Select(s => char.Parse(s))
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Client = x,
                                        ClientName = x
                                    };
                    }


                    //Inserts the client info into datbase
                objSqlCommands.sqlCommandInsertorUpdate("INSERT", records[k]);//laClient[0]);
                k++;
                    //Refreshs the Client table on display from the 
                    this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.kIIDImplementationCalcDataSet.Client);

                    //MAKE SURE TO ONLY ADD IN CLIENT AND CLIENT NAME 
                    //update the view 
                    dgvClientlst.Update() ; 





            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you understand scope of a variable. Variable K is defined inside for loop, so getting instantiated again and again to 0 in each loop. Declare K outside of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

your loop looks like this essentially :

```
foreach (string[] laClient in lsClientList)
{
   int k = 0;
   string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

   string[] fields = records[k].Split(splitChar);
   k++;
}
```

Your 'k' value never makes it past 0 for each laClient.  You need to loop internally for each line.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is not exactly what you are looking for but if you convert the .csv file to .xls file then you can manipulate it very easily. I have done this on multiple occasions and if you want I can provide you instructions with code.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jonesy's answer (because I can't yet comment), declare the variable `k` outside the loop.  It's being reset to zero each time through.

```
int k = 0;
foreach (string[] laClient in lsClientList)
{
    string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

    string[] fields = records[k].Split(splitChar);
    k++;
}
```

Comment: putting the K outside the loop fixes the problem of getting more than just the first line in but now I'm facing the problem of the select not working so I'm getting all of the data instead of the specified substring

Comment: Duh. Need to loop over the records and lines within the foreach block. As I have demonstrated, one is never too experienced to commit a noob mistake.